# Form loaded via AJAX delay and show div on submit

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery to load a form via AJAX. I want to show a div on submit before the user is sent to the return url. I've tried several solutions but the div is never shown.

```
// Delay form from being submitted
$('#order-btn').live('click', function() { 
    $('#processing_alert').show('fast', function() {
        $('#order').submit();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Ideally I'd like to delay the form a short time show the user has time to read the message before the form is sent.

Comment: I would recommend a timeout and/or the div shows always and has a button to close it.

Comment: I would also not use live() for the event binding, it is deprecated and in your case with the selector being an ID, not efficient at all. Just use click() instead, or the newer on() function.

Comment: Try to use the .submit() event of your form to display the div

Comment: @StevenHunt Don't I need the live() since the form and the #order-btn submit button were loaded in via AJAX?

Comment: You can use on() instead, it can dynamically bind events like live() can, but the event doesn't have to bubble all the way up to the document level. live() was deprecated in favor of delegate(), and it was also deprecated in favor of on(). http://api.jquery.com/on/